# Need to write script for ESXi for fetching hardware info

Tags: python, esxi

One of my project requirement, I need to write script to fetch hardware info of esxi server remotely.

If some has explored python module pywbem for esxi or some other module.

Comment: Not in python, I got similar in powershell [answered in vmtn communities]  https://www.vmspot.com/collecting-esxi-host-hardware-information-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Not in python, I got similar in powershell [answered in vmtn communities]

https://www.vmspot.com/collecting-esxi-host-hardware-information-with-powershell/

In this blog, mention script helps